# Book about a water bubble connect to oceans

Tags: story-identification

I read this book +20 years ago.
What I remember is the following:

Someone built a device that in case the water of the ocean rise it would be transported to a bubble in space, and in case the water drops the water from the bubble would flow back to the oceans.

Inside the bubble are also people, lost submarine and a intelligent "slime" that control them and also sharks and other fish.
The slime send woman back to earth. The rest I don't remember.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is Bob Shaw's *[Medusa's Children](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?5140)* (1977).

An ancient sea level regulating system teleports excess seawater to a place in space. It forms a huge bubble where sealife and people who got trapped in the transfer form an ecosystem.

The protagonist gets involved by discovering a creature that came through the transfer machinery the other way, to Earth. He winds up in the bubble.

You can read a review with more info [here](http://english.netmassimo.com/2013/03/31/medusas-children-by-bob-shaw/).

I got this book from the Science Fiction Book Club back in the day. It had an unfortunate cover.

[image: Cover of "Medusa's Children", with the description "Something alien and invincible was invading the seas of earth". The cover shows a white face with light blue tendrils extending outwards from it, set between a pink sky and a black mountain silhouette.]

Comment: Unfortunate cover? He looks like the banjo kid from Deliverance!